# error when running .awk script

Tags: awk

I have an awk script:

```
BEGIN { FS="_" }
/^>/ {
    id=$1;p=$2; wild=$3;subs=$4; c=$NF; next
}
{
    if (p-10<1) s=1
    else if (p+10>length($0)) s=length($0)-20
    else s=p-10
    print id"_"p"_"wild"_"subs">\n"substr($0,s,p-s) c substr($0,p+1,21-p+s)
}
```

and when I run I get the following:

```
$ cat test1.fasta | awk -f snp_flank.awk
bash: /usr/bin/awk: /usr/bin/awk: bad interpreter: Too many levels of symbolic links
```

what does this mean?

extra info:

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin/awk
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 21 2011-12-07 16:47 /usr/bin/awk -> /etc/alternatives/awk


$ head -n10 /usr/bin/awk
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN { FS="_" }
/^>/ {
    id=$1;p=$2; wild=$3;subs=$4; c=$NF; next
}
{
    if (p-10<1) s=1
    else if (p+10>length($0)) s=length($0)-20
    else s=p-10
```

it appears I have accidentally replaced awk with an awk script! sorry! how do I fix this? would simply reinstalling awk sort this out?

Comment: What is `/usr/bin/awk` on that system? What do `file /usr/bin/awk` and `head -n1 /usr/bin/awk` say?

Comment: What is the result of the command: `ls -l /usr/bin/awk` ? Is this file a symbolic link to another file? I think there is a link loop.

Comment: it appears I have overwritten the awk program with my awk script!! how this happened i do not know. would a simple re-install of awk work?

Comment: Yep, that should solve your problem.

Comment: Make sure you don't do software development as `root`.  Make sure no-one except root can modify the directory `/usr/bin` (or `/bin`, `/sbin`, `/usr/sbin`, `/etc`, etc), and that no-one except root can modify the files in those directories.  You should not be able to overwrite `/usr/bin/awk` running as an ordinary mortal user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have accidentally overwritten `/usr/bin/awk`.

Reinstall awk on your system.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gawk
```

or

```
sudo yum reinstall gawk
```

depending on your system.